# Make discord bot play songs from spotify

Tags: python, discord.py

Currently, my discord bot only plays music from youtube, but I want it to also play music from Spotify if requested. I heard I can use the spotipy module to do this, but I am a beginner and I'm having a hard time understanding the docs.

Comment: Spotify music is encrypted and extremely secure. Most bots that support Spotify get the name and artist then search it on youtube then get the video link and play it that way. and yeah spotipy can be used for this

Comment: In an easy way to say, Spotify doesn't allow bots to stream music. Its against their TOS

Comment: ohh ok thank you